# Wildcard match in Liquid tag?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to filter out part of a post from my site's RSS feed. I want the rest of the post, but just want to remove certain parts.

Is there a way to filter this out somehow? I've looked at these Liquid tags/filters, and the closest I've found were `remove` and `replace`, but they seem to match literally.

I'm trying to basically do this in my `feed.xml`:

`{{ post.content | replace:'<span class="no-rss">*</span>','' | cdata_escape }}`

Is there some way to use a wildcard in these filters, or achieve this otherwise that I'm not aware of? My Google-fu has run dry on this one.

Answer (score 4):

Two solutions :

### using excerpt with posts

Part of the post you want to inject in your feed is at the beginning of your post.

Use [excerpt](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts)

### isolating part of content with liquid filters

If you are in a [page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/) (they don't have excerpt), or in a post and want to select specific part of your content, you can use liquid filters.
[string.split](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#split) and [array filters](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/array-filters).

#### In any post or page

```
---
your front matter variables here
---
Head of my document
<!-- start -->
Text to extract
<!-- end -->
Bottom of my document
```

#### in your rss

```
{% for p in site.posts %}
    {% if p.content contains "<!--start-->" %}
        {% assign extract = p.content | split: "<!--start-->" | last | split: "<!--end-->" | first %}
        {{ extract }}
    {% else %}
        {{ p.content }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the whole span you could get rid of the style class being applied to it:

```
{{ post.content | remove: ' class="no-rss"' | cdata_escape }}
```